# GridView Stretching ImageView Non-Uniformly

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, stretch

I have a GridView that I am using to display a row of 4 images, each image is 200 x 200 pixels. Here is the layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/myGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:numColumns="4" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run my app here is what the images look like:

[image: grid view with 4 images]

As you can see the images are getting scaled (narrowed) to fit the screen.

How do I make it so the images are stretched both vertically and horizontally to maintain the correct aspect ratio?

Note that I am using an adapter to *draw* the images:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(imageIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Have You tried to sue imageView.setImageResource instead of setBackgroundResource ?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue in last weak.Use my image view class and solve this issue.

```
public class iv_autoSizedImageView extends ImageView {

    public iv_autoSizedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        try {

            getLayoutParams().height = getMeasuredWidth();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

        }

    }

}
```

> layout.xml

```
 <com.sample.test.iv_autoSizedImageView
            android:id="@+id/IV_NEWS_IMAGE"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```